# S3 GetObject returns content but reading from the body does not fill the buffer

Tags: go, amazon-s3

i am getting a file from s3 using the go sdk.
Although the response indicate a ContentLength the actual read from the body does not fill my buffer.

response

```
{
AcceptRanges: "bytes",
Body: buffer(0xc0421d6cc0),
ContentEncoding: "utf-8",
ContentLength: 13,
ContentType: "application/json",
ETag: "\"a15ce1024b219fd76684ba1561d23ccc\"",
LastModified: 2017-02-09 15:16:45 +0000 UTC,
Metadata: {
}
}
```

code

```
var buf []byte

r, err := resp.Body.Read(buf)
if err != nil {
    return "", err
}
defer resp.Body.Close()

fmt.Printf("read %d, buff %d", r, len(buf))
```

`"read 0, buff 0"`

Comment: Your buffer is nil, so you're reading nothing. I think you're looking for the functionality of [`ioutil.ReadAll`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadAll).

Comment: @JimB thanks that's it. You can add a answer so i can upvote if you like

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An [`io.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader) requires a slice to read into. If you don't provide any buffer space, nothing will be read.

If you want to read the entire stream into memory, you can use the [`ioutil.ReadAll`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadAll) convenience function.